# CSS style for links pointing to the current page?

Tags: css, hyperlink, css-selectors

I was wondering if there is any way in CSS3 to style links pointing to the same page that are already displayed in the browser—for example to highlight it red in the navigation telling the user "You are here right now!" since I have few lists with links, and I expect some users will probably read them one-by-one.

So if the browser is at `/features/feature3.php`, then obviously I would like to change the appearance of all links with the same `href` destination.

It seems like there is only `:hover`, `:focus`, and `:active`, but nothing to solve this problem purely in CSS. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you can use jQuery, you can write some scripts like if document.location === etc... and then add the "active" class to an element, in which you'll be able to highlight with standard CSS...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use CSS3 attribute selectors for this.

```
a[href='your url'] { *** }
```

Comment: Won't necessarily work, unless you test for `./your_url`, `/path/to/your_url`, `http://domain.com/path/to/your_url`, and even `//domain.com/path/to/your_url`... and `../../path/to/../to/your_url`.......

Comment: @Kolink: `a[href $= 'your url']` Represents an element with the href attribute whose value ends with the suffix "your url". so you don't need to test for all above.

Comment: Fair enough. Unless you're on `http://example.com/path/to/file.html` and your link is to `http://hax.com/totally/evil/file.html` ;)

Comment: This won't work in IE 6-8. You'll need some extra javascript like http://selectivizr.com/ or you can do it in JQuery/Mootools. If you DON'T need to program for IE 6-8, please let me know where you work and if they're hiring! ;)

Comment: @Lamariffic: if you can see the question again, it is tag for css3.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal Please add the `a[href $=...` approach to your answer. Also the css3 tag is irrelevant here. This is not a css3 issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try for this **[Example](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css)**, good enough helpfull.

```
<ul id="navlist">
   <li><a href="index.html" id="homenav">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="products.html" id="prodnav">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="faq.html" id="faqnav">FAQ</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html" id="connav">contact us</a></li>
</ul>

<body id="home">

body#home a#homenav,
body#products a#prodnav,
body#faq a#faqnav,
body#contact a#connav {
   color: #fff;
   background: #930;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but not very practical on a ~500 pages site. Plus i would have to 'id each and every link on my site...?!

Answer (score 1):

So CSS doesn't currently have this functionality directly supported. Thus you have to look for alternatives and weigh the trade-offs.

#### Use JavaScript and jQuery to add a class

```
$(function () {
  $('a[href="' + document.location.pathname + '"]').addClass("current");
});
```

Then you can base your styles around the `.current` selector.

```
a.current {background-color: white;}
```

Just don't put `class="current"` in your HTML - let them all be normal when the page loads and the javascript will add the class to the correct element(s). This is nice because it will work for any page and doesn't require dynamic code on the server. Of course this can be done without jQuery as well. This may need adjustment for query string parameters, absolute URLs, and a few other edge cases, but works fine for the straightforward case.

#### Use dynamic code on the server side to put class="current" on the proper elements

You could do it this way as well but it won't be quite as concise and expressive as the JavaScript version because most server side programming environments don't have the nice DOM selectors available.