# Applying a style to an active hyperlink without giving each hyperlink a class

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I want users to know what page they are currently on by highlighting the hyperlink.

I'm not using a list of buttons if that matters (`<li>`), I'm just using links.

I don't want to have to give each link a class on each page to tell if it's active or not.

Is there anyway of doing this without giving each active link a class?

I've looked into this issue and from what I see jQuery can be a possibility but I'd prefer to use it as I'm not clued up on jQuery. If anyone does know of any jQuery solutions I'll be happy to look at them!

Any automatic active link detectors about? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998574/css-style-for-links-pointing-to-the-current-page ;)

Comment: Thanks @Entropy but that link doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: I know, the link is basically saying that you can't do that with CSS but you are forced to use javascript (not necessarily jQuery, but still javascript). :)

Comment: I thought so :(, do you recommend any JQuery solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I would approach this by grabbing all `<a>` elements (or ones in a certain grouping, or in a class, like navigation) and checking if the CURRENT URL == `a.href`

Something like so:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var idx= 0; idx < a.length; ++idx){
    if(a[idx].href == document.URL){
        // some styles here to the link background
        a[idx].style.backgroundColor = 'red';  
    }
}
```

If you add in jQuery it will make your selector easier for styling and the like.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm new to JQuery so will do some research into how I add this into my website and give it a go. Would this go in with the css file or a new file and then '//do some styles' will direct it to my css files?

Comment: You can include it `inline` using `<script></script>` tags on the pages you need, OR include a javascript file on each page with this code ex: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: The one posted by Jakub is just javascript. jQuery would just make it easier and cleaner, but if you just have to do that I suggest to use simple javascript, replacing that `// do some styles` with a code that add a class to the href (live .active-url) and then manage the styling part in the CSS sheet.

Comment: I've added a quick 'background-color' style, and removed debug piece.

Comment: This didn't work but I'm worried it has something to do with the way my buttons have been written. They aren't using navigations bars <ul> and <li> etc... they are all in a div. Each button has a div and a class that I have given it. Also a hyperlink of course and that is all.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work but I haven't tested it. 
It's using jQuery and it's pretty readable.

You should however process the path name to have just the part needed for the match in the hrefHasPath function.

```
var links = $("#links a");               // gets all links within something with an id of "links"
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // current url
//for each link see if the href has something in the path, and if it does add a css class
$.each(links, function(){ 
    if(hrefHasPath($(this).attr("href"))){
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    } 
});

function hrefHasPath(href){
    return (href.indexOf("pathname ") != -1);
}
```

Comment: This hasn't worked either but I'm sure it's because I'm not using it properly. I've got the script at the top. I've got a class called '#highlight' in the css and I've got my button but they don't change when I go to them (when they're active).